# How would I add, delete or insert arrays in Java using static methods (no ArrayLists)

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods

I am trying to self-learn Java, and have an issue with these arrays I have to make without ArrayLists. I tried to look online on static methods, but I can't find anything that could help me understand. I have to make 3 methods that can be used to modify arrays. So, for adding a value to the end of an array, the method should have the array and the value as parameters.  It should then return a new array which is the same as the old array but with the added on value. The site I'm trying to learn this on shows me the block of code and explains what methods do, but it doesn't show me how to use them.

```
public class Arrays {
    static void array() {
        System.out.print("1, 2, 4, 7");
    }
    static void add() {
        System.out.print(", 11");
    }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Array:");
        array();
        System.out.println(" ");    

        System.out.println("Array with Added End:");
        array();
        add();
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialize an array and write this array in the parameters of the static methods. I really don't get whether you are asking for static methods or arrays

Comment: You don't have any arrays in your program; printing out a list of numbers  does not make an array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...for adding a value to the end of an array, the method should have the array and the value as parameters.  It should then return a new array which is the same as the old array but with the added on value.

I'm going to assume that `add` is the method that will add something to your array and that your array is of type `int[]`. I'll build the method step-by-step:

**method should have the array and the value as parameters**

```java
add(int[] arr, int val) {}
```

**It should then return a new array which is the same as the old array**

The return type of the method must therefore be the same as the array parameter `arr`.  Since you stated the method must be static:

```java
public static int[] add(int[] arr, int val)
{
    // todo: make this work
}
```

**It should then return a new array which is the same as the old array but with the added on value.**

Arrays cannot be resized so you need to create a new array (which is also specified in the instructions) that is large enough to hold all the elements of `arr` plus one additional element. There are several ways to populate your new array:

Copying each element yourself:

```java
public static int[] add(int[] arr, int val)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[arr.length + 1];
    for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
    {
      newArray[index] = arr[index];
    }
    // Arrays start at index 0 so arr.length will be the last
    // position in newArray.
    newArray[arr.length] = val;
    return newArray;
}
```

Using `java.util.Arrays`:

```java
public static int[] add(int[] arr, int val)
{
    int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length + 1);
    newArray[arr.length] = val;
    return newArray;
}
```

Using `System.arraycopy`:

```java
public static int[] add(int[] arr, int val)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[arr.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, newArray, 0, arr.length);
    newArray[arr.length] = val;
    return newArray;
}
```

This should be enough of an example on working with arrays to help you write the other two methods.